# Need effective name of a button which can explain that by clicking it user will be able to perform certain operation

Tags: buttons, call-to-action, names

I am designing menu part for the restaurant in which I want to set a button on the top of menu list which will contains 3 operations those are : Manage Images, Edit Menu Content,Delete Menu.

Manage images : this will have functionality to change or add the images of items.
Edit Content : this will have functionality to edit text of menu only.
Delete Menu : by clicking this user will have 3 choice that which part he want to remove(i.e.Food Category or Food Items).

I tried many different layouts and ways but finally thought to give common button instead of 3 different button at the top of Menu.

Please suggest me what to do.

Comment: How about a button titled edit? This could be supported with a pencil icon?

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be a good idea to use one button (or what looks like one button) to do those 3 tasks because they're very different.  If you use one button on the top level, you'll still have to use 3 buttons, or things that do the same job as a button, at the next level in order to bring the person to the point where they can do that particular work.  Providing only one button at the outer level just adds an un-needed step.

Use 3 buttons, with icons on them so that new people can understand quickly which button they want to click.  Good icons are particularly helpful for people who might have difficulty when reading words.

I would suggest a picture frame showing food, an image of a pencil on a sheet of paper with the local word for "MENU" at the top, and perhaps a paper menu torn in half for the third button.  But you should use whatever images you feel would be understandable to the people using the software.